# Laravel 5.1 job works if immediate but fails if queued due to Eloquent model error

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs

I have a Laravel job that I dispatch to read customer data from a file. The job has a logger model dependency, and this logger tracks certain stats then writes to a log db table when the job completes. When I dispatch this job immediately it works fine, but if I queue the exact same job with the exact same parameters and then run it from the queue it fails with the error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException]               
  No query results for model [app\Models\MyModel].
```

I think this is due to the serialize/unserialize nature inherent in the Laravel queue system which breaks Eloquent, which tries the findOrFail() method when I am never actually trying to find something in the db. I am merely creating a new log from a blank model. Whatever the case, it is clear that the same Laravel job, when not queued, runs fine -- but it fails when queued. I am at a loss and wondering if there is a way to work around this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: can you add all your code? the `dispatch` function calling the queue job and the Job itself?

Answer (score 2):

I worked around it by instantiating and then saving the model object before passing it into the job's constructor, so it at least has a primary key set. This eliminates the findOrFail() method. A little hacky but it's the best I could come up with.

Comment: This is the only way to do it, nothing hacky. Remember that the queue worker/listener has booted it's own copy of the framework in the backend so it wont have access to any eloquent objects you pass to it unless you call ->save() on them first. This is an easy mistake to make if you are testing with the "sync" queue driver but using a real queue in production.

Comment: From my testing it appears that instantiating a new eloquent model in the constructor of a queued job calls findOrFail() and breaks it. So I can save() it before the job and pass it in. But I can also move the exact same code to the handle() method and instantiate a new eloquent model, and that also works. So there's another possible solution.

Comment: I think I'm facing the same issue as your question. 
I am trying to do an update within the `handle()` method however the queue keeps looping whenever I try to do a database call within the `handle()` method. Did you manage to do any updates within the `handle()` method?

Answer (score -3):

Make an error handler (put it in your routes)

```
App::error(function(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e)
{
    return Response::make('Not found',404);
});
```

Comment: This runs as a job from the db queue, not as a web page.

Comment: I am sorry about that. Please disregard my answer. thanks